# Cómo utilizar un foreach para un HashMap sin lambda?

Tags: java

Tengo dos HashMap y me gustaría solo comparar las claves pero primero necesito saber como utilizar el foreach para recorrer los datos.

```
public class CAsignatura {

 HashMap<Short, String> asignatura = new HashMap();

 CAsignatura alumno = new CAsignatura():

  alumno.put(1234, "Fundamentos básicos");
  alumno.put(1235, "Contabilidad básica");

 }


public class CEstudios {

HashMap<Short, String> asignatura = new HashMap();

CEstudios asignaturas = new CEstudios():

asignaturas.put(1235, "Fundamentos básicos");
asignaturas.put(1234, "Contabilidad básica");

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te presento 2 formas, la primera con un `for` y la otra con Lambda

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Short, String> asignatura = new HashMap();


        asignatura.put((short)1234, "Fundamentos básicos");
        asignatura.put((short)1235, "Contabilidad básica");
        
        //opción 1
        for(Map.Entry<Short, String> entry : asignatura.entrySet()) {
            Short key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(key + " -> " + value);
        }

        //opción 2
        asignatura.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+ " -> " + v));
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo más común es iterar de esta forma es definiendo los valores a obtener del mapa como `Short` para la key, y de tipo `String` para el valor:

```
   HashMap<Short, String> alumno = new HashMap();

   CAsignatura alumno = new CAsignatura():

   alumno.put((short)1234, "Fundamentos básicos");
   alumno.put((short)1235, "Contabilidad básica");

    for(Map.Entry<Short, String> entry : alumno.entrySet()) {
        Short key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("key: " + key + " , value: " + value);
   }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda!!